# how to deal with characters of a string when we are using string instead of character array?

Tags: c++

for example 
if I am declaring my string as

```
string s;
cin>>s;
```

And if I want to deal with each character of string .

Comment: What do you want to do with it?

Comment: @luk32: He said that: "deal with it". Question not a man's motives when dealing with the shady characters around him.

Comment: Well transforming is a bit different than "making them gone", that could influence suggested approaches.

Comment: learn basics of C++ - classes, methods, operators and always check documentation of any stl construct you are using (for this case : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/ )

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop:

```
for (char c : s)
{
    std::cout << "Character '" << c << "'\n";
}
```

Alternatively:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i != s.size(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << "Character " << i << " is '" << s[i] << "'\n";
}
```

Comment: Consider `std::transform`, and you can even use `deal` as `UnaryOperation`.